# Racket how to define a recursive generator like Python?

Tags: recursion, scheme, generator, racket, powerset

This is a recursive algorithm to yield all subsets of a set. the equivalent Python code is:

```
def subsets(s):
    if not s:
        yield ()
    else:
        for e in subsets(s[1:]):
            yield s[:1] + e
            yield e

for s in subsets((1,2,3)):
    print(s)
```

Result:

```
>>> 
(1, 2, 3)
(2, 3)
(1, 3)
(3,)
(1, 2)
(2,)
(1,)
()
```

This is the Racket version I tried:

```
#lang racket
(require racket/generator)

(define (subsets x)
  (generator ()
   (let recur ([s x])
     (if (null? s) 
         (yield '())
         (for ([e (in-producer (recur (cdr s)))])
           (yield (cons (car s) e))
           (yield e))))))

(for/list ([j (in-producer (subsets '(1 2 3)))])
    (display j))
```

But it doesn't work:

```
Welcome to DrRacket, version 6.0.1 [3m].
Language: racket; memory limit: 128 MB.
(). . result arity mismatch;
 expected number of values not received
  expected: 1
  received: 0
  values...:
```

There seems to be no related example in Racket documentation Is it possible, how?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You were overall pretty close, with some minor issues:

- You made the `subsets` function get the set and return a generator
  properly, but then you decided to wrap the body in the `recur` loop
  for no good reason...  You want the recursive call to return a
  generator (to be used as a producer) so you just need to call
  `subsets`.
- The proper way to iterate over a generator is to make it return some
  known value when it's done, and use that as a stop-value.  For
  example, add a (void) in the end and use it to stop.
- You shouldn't mix `for/list` and `display` -- the first is used to
  collect a list of results and the second is used to display a value.
  Either switch to `for`, or just drop the `display` to return the list
  of subsets.

Fixing these gives working code:

```
#lang racket
(require racket/generator)

(define (subsets s)
  (generator ()
    (if (null? s)
      (yield '())
      (for ([e (in-producer (subsets (cdr s)) (void))])
        (yield (cons (car s) e))
        (yield e)))
    (void)))

(for ([j (in-producer (subsets '(1 2 3)) (void))])
  (displayln j))
```

Two side comments:

- A minor comment about Oscar's solution: using `in-generator` can be a
  little confusing since it's not a way to iterate over a generator but
  instead it's a way to *create* a generator and immediately iterate
  over it.
- JFYI, this is not really a good way to do this if you care about
  efficiency (rather than play around with generators).

Comment: @ Today I found your solution is better because your version can be used standalone i.e. (define g (subsets 3)) (display (g)). And also you provide a lot useful tips. So it's yours.

Answer (score 2):

I think the procedure can be simplified a bit. The following is equivalent to the code in Python, and notice how we use [`in-generator`](http://docs.racket-lang.org/reference/Generators.html#%28form._%28%28lib._racket%2Fgenerator..rkt%29._in-generator%29%29):

```
(require racket/generator)

(define (subsets s)
  (if (null? s) 
      (yield '())
      (for ([e (in-generator (subsets (cdr s)))])
        (yield (cons (car s) e))
        (yield e))))
```

Call it like this:

```
(for ([e (in-generator (subsets '(1 2 3)))])
  (displayln e))

=> (1 2 3)
   (2 3)
   (1 3)
   (3)
   (1 2)
   (2)
   (1)
   ()
```

Comment: One problem with this answer is that `subsets` is a function that should only be used inside of a generator.  IOW, calling it directly won't make you happy.